# React: How to redirect to new route (different id) from same route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In `react-router,` we cannot push the same route in `useHisotry()` and cause a re-render. E.g., if component App is showing on route `https://localhost:3000` and I click the button `Click Me!`, it won't cause a re-render:

```
function App() {
   const history = useHistory();
   return (
      <button onClick={() => {history.push('/')}}> Click Me! </button>
   )
}
```

I want to achieve similar functionality, but I am unsure about the approach or what I am missing.

My current route looks like this: **https://localhost:3000/user/1**

I want to go to **user/2** by clicking a button.

My code looks like the below:

```
<Route exact path="/user/:userId" component={User} />

function User() {
   const history = useHistory();
   return (
      <button onClick={() => {history.push('/user/2')}}> Click Me! </button>
   )
}
```

The above code changes the route but doesn't re-render the component. How can I fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Check https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7415

Answer (score 2):

My advice is to upgrade to `react router dom v6` and use `useNavigate`  , tutorial [here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#navigation)

once you import `useNavigate`  from `react-router-dom`

```
let navigate = useNavigate();
```

and on your button you call this function on click passing your desired `url`

```
<button onClick={()=> navigate('/users/2')}
```

Your component's info wont change because you arent rendering anything dynamically in it, so you should grab the `userid` from the url, and then lets say display it. Check [Docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useparams)

As the answer below, you can do it exactly as he said.

```
const { userId } = useParams();
return (
    <div>userId: { userId }</div>
);
```

Comment: I would need to make other adjustments as well, I guess for that and might run into more problems so not an option rn

Comment: @newbie does your button redirect you to `/user/2` in the url or not ?

Comment: The url changes but the component doesn't change

Comment: @newbie ofcourse it wont change because you are rendering the same data inside.. try to grab the `user id` from the url, and display it in the component dynamically. try using `useParams` to grab the id.
Check the docs
https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useparams

Comment: Thanks I am able to fix it.. the issue was something different but thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend using `history` for this case.
If you really need to, inside `User` component get userId parameter and react on that.

```
<Route exact path='/user/:userId' component={User} />

const User = () => {
    const { userId } = useParams();
    return (
        <div>userId: { userId }</div>
    );
}
export default User;
```

Comment: Thanks I am able to fix it.. the issue was something different but thanks for the help

Comment: @newbie  perfect!

Comment: @newbie, can you help me with how you fix this, I have a class component for this, and doing API call in the component did mount.